# hibernate one-to-many detach child object from parent relationship

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, relationship

I have 2 entities `film` (Parent) and `episode` (Child) with one-to-many relationship, whenever I create a `film` object with collection of `episode` objects, everything works normal, parent and related child objects are created. But when I try to update a `film' by removing bunch of 'episode' objects nothing seems to work out

Here what I am trying to do, When i remove a bunch of `episode` objects from `film`, those removed objects should not be deleted **but kept as episode without linked to any parent object**. Is this possible?

**Film** entity

```
    import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "FILM")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Film {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_TITLE", nullable = false)
        private String originalTitle;


        @OneToMany(targetEntity=FilmEpisode.class, mappedBy="film", cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Set<FilmEpisode> filmEpisodes;

        @Column(name = "SHOW_ON_LANDING_PAGE")
        private Boolean showOnLandingPage;
    }
```

**FilmEpisode** entity

```
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "FILM_EPISODE")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class FilmEpisode {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_TITLE", nullable = false)
        private String originalTitle;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "FILM_ID")
        private Film film;
    }
```

In DAO I am just saving `film` with `saveOrUpdate` method like below

```
session.saveOrUpdate(film);
```

Am I missing something..??

Answer (score 1):

`orphanRemoval = true` is making unreferenced entities from parent entity being deleted. 
Change it to `orphanRemoval = false` and child entities will not be removed from database. You can delete it too as it defaults to `false`:

Comment: Yes i tried that, child objects those removed from collection are not updated. So tried to check by giving `orphanRemoval = true` even that didn't work, could not delete children records.

Comment: If you have bidirectional mappings i believe you have to remove relation in both sides.

Comment: So you have to remove the `Film` from the `Episode` side.

Comment: But does that related to the problem that I am facing, Bcoz I need mapping for fetching `film` along with `episode` and `episode` along with `film`.

Comment: Remove the related `Film` from the `Episode` entity, as you have done with the `Episodes` in the `Film` object. Remove the objects, not the relationship in the entity definition.

Comment: Does Cascade Detach increase version number of a record

Answer (score 0):

In .NET I had the same problem to exclude a child.
I decided carrying a session from parent and then setting a merge in session .

Using:

`Map Parent`

`HasMany(x => x.Child)
         .KeyColumn("id")
         .AllDeleteOrphan();`

On Update method:

```
public void Update(Parent model)
{
   var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

   using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
   {
       session.Load<Parent>(model.Id);
       session.Merge(model);
       transaction.Commit();
   }
}
```

To load the list in .load in the database, returned three rows, and the last object in the method has only 2 rows. Making the .Commit, the line I removed the object was deleted from the database.